# Get keys inside quotes with regex

Tags: regex, json

I have JSON of this style:

```
define({
  somekey : "Some {text} here:",
  'some-key' : "Text:",
  'key/key' : 'Some : text',
  key: 'some value',
  'my-key' : 'my text',
  'my/key' : 'my topic text'
  "my-key" : "my topic text"
});
```

I need to extend this regex `(?m)^[ ]*([^\r\n:]+?)\s*:/g` so that I get keys without quotes.

In the example above I want to get: `somekey, some-key, key/key, key, my-key, my/key, my-key` (the quotes are ignored if they exist and only keys are returned).

Example is [here](http://regex101.com/r/rU0pO8) but it returns keys with quotes.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Parsing JSON manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this regex,

```
(?m)^[ ]*\'?\"?([\w-/]+)\'?\"?\s*:
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fE3gN2)

OR

```
(?m)^[ ]*\'?\"?([^'"(\s]+)\'?\"??\s*:
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xD6oL3)

Answer (score 1):

Just make them optional:

```
(?m)^ *'?([^'\r\n:]+?)'?\s*:/g
```